# meaning of * in ruby function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a basic question about the mearning of * in a function call which I haven't been able to understand from online docs:

```
def self.new(*args, &block)
```

What does *args mean in the function call above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider a following method

```
def user(user_name)
  puts user_name
end
```

so when you call

```
user("RPV")

Output: 
RPV
=> nil
```

but what if you pass more then one argument like

```
user("RPV", "Marek")
```

it will give an error

**wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)**

To avoid this kind of error splat(*) operator is helpful

```
def user(*user_name)
  puts user_name
end
```

and when you pass more than one argument it handles converts it in array

```
user("RPV", "Marek")

output:
RPV
Marek
nil
```

it makes user_name as an array

```
def user(user_name)
  p user_name
end

user("RPV", "Marek")

output:

 ["RPV", "Marek"]
```

Hope you got the use of it.

Answer (score 2):

It means you can pass any number of arguments that will be stored in `args` table inside of this method. Take a look: https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/